# A regular expression with a value obtained from FormControl does not work

Tags: typescript

Here is the code

```
  public phoneNumber: string = "31031234567";

  phoneForm : FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    phoneFormControl: new FormControl('8356532235', [
      Validators.required ]),
      ...
  });

  get phoneFormControl() { return this.phoneForm.get('phoneFormControl')!; }

  next() {
    let regexpPhone: RegExp = /^[0-9]{10}$/;

    if (this.phoneForm.value == null) {      return;    }

    this.phoneNumber = this.phoneForm.value;
    console.log("phoneNumber= " , this.phoneNumber);

    alert( regexpPhone.test(this.phoneNumber) );    
  }
```

I save a string from the input form in the PhoneNumber variable.

PhoneNumber of type string

The console displays what was entered in the form.
But when checking it with regexp Phone.test always gets false.

Comment: try this `new FormControl('', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^[0-9]{10}$')]))`

Comment: Yes, I use such a validator. And not one, several are used. But I can't block the button for these all validator. So I duplicate the check in the component.

Comment: but why you used string instead of number.

use number and on the api call set as string using .toString() method

Comment: I tried this.phone Number = this.phoneForm.value.toString(); It doesn't work that way at all.
phone Number =  [object Object]

Comment: user this this.phoneForm.value.phoneNumber.toString();

Comment: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toString')

Comment: Thank you all! I found a solution with your help:
this.phone Number = this.phoneForm.value.phone Form Control.toString();